# How do I set the pixels on an image at diagonal in a specific area using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, image

Im trying to make this image:

[image]

look like this image:

[image]

I am having a problem getting a diagonal line in red on the bottom left.

Here is my code:

```
var img = new SimpleImage(200,200);
var w = img.getWidth();
var xPos = 20;

for(var p of img.values())
{
    //set canvas to red
    p.setRed(255);

    if(p.getX() <= w/10 && p.getY() <= w/1)
    {
        //set 20px border along left side of img to black
        p.setRed(0);

        //set top diag corner
        if(p.getX() >= (p.getY() + 1))
        {
            p.setRed(255);
        }
    }

    //Problem is here  
    if(p.getY() >= 180)
    {
        if(p.getX() >= xPos)
        {
            p.setRed(85);
        }
    }

    xPos--;
}

print(img);
```

My problem is that my xPos variable in my last condition seems to not be reading the value from the var declaration. When I set it to the hard coded number it kind of reacts the way a want.

The bottom shade of red is what i am working on to visualize the creation of the bottom diagonal.

I am confused about the direction I took on this particular bit of code Im doing for fun because the execution of the script isnt going as intended.

What I am trying to do is that every pixel on the Y-axis of the image, measuring from top to bottom, is to be setRed(255) if its Y coord. is greater than 180 which is where the diagonal should start.

Once that initial condition is met, I am then coding the program to paint every pixel setRed(), if its x coord. is greater than the variable xPos which is initially set at 20 since 20 pixels is where the diagonal should start at every pixel whose Y coord. is greater than 180.

Since I am trying to paint the pixels in order to achieve a red diagonal that terminates at the bottom left of the image where it transitions to black, I then continue to subtract 1 from the Global xPos variable so that in the next iteration of the for loop it paints the image red one more pixel to the left.

For some reason my variables dont seem to be registering when called by the for loop, mainly xPos, and I feel like i understand the process I have to go through to create this algorithm, but I can get it to work.

How do I create a program/script in javascript that will help be draw that diagonal starting at the bottom left hand side of the image.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to solving the problem is recognizing that you essentially have 3 functions that you need to calculate.

The first deals with the diagonal part at the top, the second deals with the rectangle between the top diag and the bottom one, while the third function is responsible for the bottom diagonal.

1. For the first function, you only want to draw a pixel if the X coord
   is lower or equal to the Y coord.
2. For the second function, you simply fill.
3. For the third function, you only want to fill if the X coord is less
   than the difference between the image height and the current Y
   coord.

Here's a vanilla JS solution:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
"use strict";
function byId(id){return document.getElementById(id);}

window.addEventListener('load', onDocLoaded, false);

var imgData;

function onDocLoaded()
{
    var can = byId('tgt');
    var ctx = can.getContext('2d');

    imgData = ctx.getImageData(0,0,can.width,can.height);
    doTest();
    updateCan();
}

function setPixel(x,y, r,g,b, imgData)
{
    var index = ((imgData.width * y) + x) * 4;
    imgData.data[index] = r;
    imgData.data[index+1] = g;
    imgData.data[index+2] = b;
    imgData.data[index+3] = 255;   // alpha value
}

function updateCan()
{
    var can = byId('tgt');
    can.getContext('2d').putImageData(imgData,0,0);
}

function doTest()
{
    var margin = 32;
    var x, y;

    for (y=0; y<imgData.height; y++)
    {
        for (x=0; x<margin; x++)
        {
            // function 1 - top diag
            if (y < margin)
            {
                if (x < y)
                    setPixel(x,y, 255,0,0, imgData);
            }

            // function 2 - middle rect
            else if ((y >= margin) && (y < imgData.height-margin))
                setPixel(x,y, 0,255,0, imgData);

            // function 3 - bottom diag
            else 
            {
                var tmpY = imgData.height - y;
                if (x < tmpY)
                    setPixel(x,y, 0,0,255, imgData);
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
<style>
canvas
{
    border: solid 1px black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id='tgt' width='256' height='256'></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "For the third function, you only want to fill if the X coord is less than the difference between the image height and the current Y coord." 

Thanks so much! thats the exact sentence I needed to get my head around that one!!!

Much appreciated